# NSXMLParser I implemented with Swift works on iOS 8 but not on 7.1

Tags: ios7, swift, ios8

Long story short, I was pulling some data from a RSS feed and everything was working good. Well, untill I decided to test it on the iOS 7.1 simulator. It crashed right away.

Here is the XML Parser I created in the ViewDidLoad:

```
    var parser = NSXMLParser()
    var url: NSURL = NSURL.URLWithString("http://exampleURLforthisPost.com/?feed=rss2")

    parser = NSXMLParser (contentsOfURL: url)

    parser.delegate = self

    parser.shouldProcessNamespaces = false

    parser.shouldReportNamespacePrefixes = false

    parser.shouldResolveExternalEntities = false

    parser.parse()
```

It works fine with iOS 8 but when I run it with iOS 7.1, "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error designated on the "parser = NSXMLParser (contentsOfURL: url)" line. Is there something different I should designate when running iOS 7.1?

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: what is the error message

Comment: @Bryan Chen - That is part of my issue. The console shows no information what so ever. All I can find is a green instruction pointer line on "parser = NSXMLParser (contentsOfURL: url)" stating that there was a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address0x18)" on thread one. Any advice on getting more information from Xcode?

Comment: try `var parser : NSXMLParser! =  NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: url)` and check parser is not nil

Comment: Well, that just so happened to work flawlessly for both iOS 7 and 8! Can't thank you enough! It must have to do with Swift optionals. =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
var parser : NSXMLParser! = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: url)
```

It looks like `NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: url)` may return `nil` in error case (e.g. invalid URL), so you need to assign it to an optional value to avoid unwrap nil value.

Answer (score 3):

I'm getting the same problem, under ios8. However, I have a stack trace;

```
#0  0x000000010930b87c in CFStringCreateCopy ()
#1  0x000000010ae753d4 in Foundation._convertNSStringToString (ObjectiveC.NSString) -> Swift.String ()
#2  0x0000000108a3fffb in @objc Fuel_Locator.FuelWatchReader.parser (Fuel_Locator.FuelWatchReader)(ObjectiveC.NSXMLParser, didEndElement : Swift.String, namespaceURI : Swift.String, qualifiedName : Swift.String) -> () ()
#3  0x0000000108d2c6ad in _endElementNs ()
#4  0x0000000108b1dd96 in xmlParseEndTag2 ()
#5  0x0000000108b20424 in xmlParseTryOrFinish ()
#6  0x0000000108b1f4b0 in xmlParseChunk ()
#7  0x0000000108d299be in -[NSXMLParser parseData:] ()
#8  0x0000000108d29c1f in -[NSXMLParser parseData:] ()
#9  0x0000000108d29d7a in -[NSXMLParser parseFromStream] ()
```

This result is not good, as it indicates that the problem is occurring when the parser attempts to make a swift copy of a NSString that it has read from the XML. BTW, this only happens when the `didEndElement` method is about to be called in the delegate. If the method is not present, then error don't happen… but that is hardly useful.

Comment: I have a similar problem running in Xcode 6.1 beta on Yosemite. An `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` at almost the exact same spot.